Can I log in with token with template in Clerk?
I use Expo(React Native) with Clerk. To talk to the database I use a JWT token with the template provided by the Clerk. I store this token using Expo Secure Store.
The thing is: with that token, I can easily communicate with the database, but when I close the app and open it again, I am logged out because the token with the template is not valid.
On the other hand, when I store the token without a template, it is valid for the Clerk, and I can close and open the app while logged in, but since I have no template, the token is not valid for the backend.
Does this mean that I'm required now to store two tokens? One for Clerk and another, a templated token for my backend?
